# Db.Value.AfterTable.find api change for Frama-C Aluminium

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to migrate a plugin for Frama-C Fluorine version to Frama-C Aluminium. When doing so, I cannot find the appropriate replacement for function `Db.Value.AfterTable.find`, the closest one I found is `Db.Value.AfterTable_By_Callstack.find`. However, that function now returns different type, which is `Db.Value.AfterTable_By_Callstack.data = Db.Value.state Value_types.Callstack.Hashtbl.t`, rather than `Db.Value.state` in Frama-C Fluorine. Could anyone please help me with this?

Many thanks,
Truc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the information is now more precise. But you can compute the state by joining the states by call stack with :

```
let state = Value_callstack.Callstack.Hashtbl.fold
      (fun _cs state acc -> Cvalue.Model.join acc state)
      csh Cvalue.Model.bottom
```

Comment: Where `csh` is `Db.Value.AfterTable_By_Callstack.find stmt`.